# NPM run build with React + Node + concurrently How to?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, build, concurrently

I have spend hours trying to figure this out any advice is welcome.  The objective here is to assemble a postbuild script that will work on a nodeJS app running a react client.

React is on post 3000 and node is on 5000.  So it requires the ***concurrently*** library.  Below are two attempts `do-postbuild` and `heroku-postbuild` (both fail).

```
  "scripts": {

    "server": "nodemon server.js --ignore client",
    "client": "npm start --prefix ../client",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\" ",
    "do-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix && npm run build --prefix client",
    "heroku-postbuild": "cd ../client && npm install && npm install --only=dev --no-shrinkwrap && npm run build" 
  },
```

folder structure

```
client
server
   |_package.json (above)
   |_server.js
```

> ***npm run dev***  - WORKS perfectly

When I attempt `npm run heroku-postbuild`  it yields the following:

```
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! ver1.02@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild: `cd client && npm install && npm install --only=dev --no-shrinkwrap && npm run build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
```

When attempting to write `npm run do-postbuild` it throws an error like it is searching for **client** in the **server** folder

```
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/sites/server/client/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

Comment: how did you solve this?

Comment: I stopped using concurrently and deployed production versions of the client and server separately.  Someone down voted the solution but it worked perfectly for me.

Comment: how did you deploy client and server separately on heroku?

Comment: I did my first production builds (while learning Node/React) on Heroku there are lots of guides.  The day will come as it did for me where you must be able to deploy on a native LINUX Box this is how I did it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***This is not a HEROKU solution it is for general UBUNTU server with root access.***

Solution here is you don't have to dockerize the app as a bundle (client and server together).

What worked for me was to treat the client and server as two different apps.

Client side:

- `npm run build` locally from the same folder as contains your package.json file
- then post the app `build folder` as very straight forward client side app with HTML CSS Javascript

Server side:

- upload the `server` files (not including node_modules folder)
- run `npm i`(from the folder with the package.json file)
- I set up reverse proxy to map the port to a specific location on the server for the react to reach it
- set up cron job to start server side (and check periodically to ensure it is running)

Thats it - works perfect.

Comment: sorry, I downvoted this answer and can't change it. if you edit it somehow I will have opportunity to vote up again

Comment: please try now - you do the build from the folder with the package.json file.

Answer (score 0):

Add this  in your scripts

```
 "client-install": "npm install --prefix client",
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add below Scripts and try, it will work 100%.

```
 "scripts": { 

 "client-install": "npm install --prefix client",
      "start": "node server.js",
      "server": "nodemon server.js",
      "client": "npm start --prefix client",
      "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
      "heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client"
    }
```